# Div box resizing with page?

Tags: html, css, web

I am trying to sort this problem out I am relatively new to this so please don't judge..
its the bottomright div that isnt working

It's for some additional information but it just keeps changing position when the page resizes, someone please help? thanks..
Regards, Jack.

```
<html>

    <head>

        <!--<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">-->
<style>
* {font:12px arial;padding:0px;margin:0px;}
#wrapper{
margin: 0 auto;
width: 1130px;
}

#header {position:relative;height:100px;width:1130px;}
#header img {position:absolute;top:10px;}
#nav {position:absolute;right:0px;}
#nav ul {padding: 5px; 
border-left: 1px;
text-align: center;
width: 600px;
}
#nav li {float:left;display: block;padding: 8px 15px; border-right: 2px solid #eb332c;
position:relative;top:30px;}
#nav li a:hover {color: #c00;background-color: #fff; 
}
#nav li.last{border-right:none;
}
#nav li a{
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
font-size:16px;
color:000000;
}

#headings {position:relative;height:500px;width:865px;margin:0px auto;}
#headings img {display:inline;
background-color:#ebebeb;
padding:150px 0px 50px 0px;}



#content {width:865px;margin:0px auto;}
#bottomleft {float:left;width:400px;}
#bottomright {float:right;width:200px;}



#footer {background-color:#eb322c;
width:100%;
height:140px;
clear:both;
}

#footer_content{
width:1130px;
background-color:eb332c;
margin:0px auto;
height:140px;
position:relative;
color:white;
}
h1{
background-color:#FFFFFF;
text-align:left;
font-size:30px;
position:absolute;top:60px;left:0px;
z-index:100;
width:340px;
}
h2{
font-size:20px;
position:absolute;bottom:120px;
}

h3{
font-size:20px;
position:absolute;bottom:122px;
position:absolute;right:372px;
}
h4{
font-size:20px;
position:absolute;bottom:122px;
position:absolute;right:118px;
}
h5
{
font-size:18px;
position:absolute;bottom:250px;
position:absolute;left:0px;

border-bottom: 1px solid #eb332c;
width:537px;

}

p.para{
position:relative;left:3px;bottom:25px;
font-family:arial;
font-size:12px;
width:500px;
}

#bottomleft{
position:relative;
}

#bottomright{
margin-top: -60px;
margin-right: 55px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-bottom: auto;
position:relative;
background-color:ebebeb;
width:268px;
height:220px;

}

h6.address{
border-bottom: 1px solid #eb332c;width:230px;font-size:16px;
}

</style>        
</head>
<title>
Cochranes Law Firm
</title>
<body>

    <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="header">
                <img src="images/logo.png">         

                <div id="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li class="Home"><a href="#">Home  </a></li>
                    <li class="About"><a href="#">About Us </a></li>
                    <li class="Team"><a href="#">Our team  </a></li>
                    <li class="Services"><a href="#">Our Services  </a></li>
                    <li class="last"><a href="#"> Contact Us </a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="headings">
                <h1>Local <span style="color:eb332c;font-weight:bold">Billingham</span>  Solicitors Firm    </h1>
                <img src="images/family.jpg"class="family">
                <img src="images/home.jpg"class="home">
                <img src="images/care.jpg"class="care">

                <h2>Family Law</h2>
                <h3>Buying & Selling Property</h3>
                <h4>Wills, Trusts & Probate</h4>


            </div>

            <div id="content">
                <div id="bottomleft">
                            <h5>Welcome to Cochranes Law Firm</h5>
                                <p class="para">We are a family High Street Practice, in Billingham Town Centre, providing an
                                    important service to the local community. we are wills and probate. buying and Selling, as well as Family law Solicitors in the Billingham and Stockton-on-tees area. If you would like any further information please feel free to contact us by phone, email or our contact form.
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="lorem"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed accumsan, urna sit amet euismod gravida, elit ante placerat orci, et porttitor nunc velit malesuada tortor. Nam ac nisl non nunc commodo vestibulum a eu velit. Sed vitae arcu sit amet nulla ornare fringilla sodales vel justo. Cras hendrerit libero a mauris gravida lobortis. Donec iaculis tincidunt est, non rutrum lorem dictum vitae. Curabitur non justo sed est accumsan posuere id eget justo. Nunc in justo congue, laoreet sem sed, scelerisque nulla. Fusce in urna suscipit, imperdiet purus et, ornare nunc. Ut vestibulum consectetur metus, vitae ultrices lacus placerat aliquet.</p>
                </div>

                <div id="bottomright">
                    <h6 class="address"> Contact Address</h6>
                    <p class="pclass">Cochranes Law Firm <br> 67 Queensway<br>
                        Billingham<br>TS23 2KH</p>
                        <h6 class="commonnum">Contact Numbers</h6>
                        <p class="nums">Telephone: 01642 266800<br>Fax:01642 366809<br>
                        DX 63160 BILLINGHAM</p>
                        <p class="Email">info@cochraneslawfirm.co.uk</p>
                        <h6 class="contactmail">Contact E-Mail Address</h6>

                </div>

            </div>
    </div>

<div id="footer">
    <div id="footer_content">

        <p class="foot">&copy;2014 Cochranes Law Firm | Privacy Policy | Terms and Conditions
        Web Design by MCWare IT Solutions.</p>
        <img src="images/mcware.png">
        <img src="images/accreditations.png" class="accreditations">

            <small>Cochranes Law Firm is a Limited Liability registered in England and Wales number OC343046 and our VAT number is 508 983002. The registered office is at 67 Queensway, Billingham. TS23 2LU. Authorised and regulated by the Solicitors Regulation authority number 547210 under rule 7.07(1) of the Solicitors Code Of Conduct. We have worldwide professional indemnity insurance through amtrust Europe Limited, No2 Minster Court, Minicing Lane, LONDON, EC3R 7BB. Our policy number is P13A298125P and P13B295219P.  </small>
    </div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the HTML for this CSS?

Comment: If you need to resize an element depending on window width, you must use percentage units,i.e. width:50% or something. You may also need other things for not changing position but you need to post more data and the html

Comment: @alou i've tried stuff like that and its not working, sorry if its a stupid question its just hard when your focussing and getting stressed is all

Comment: @RazorJack I've added it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my take on it, keep in mind that i can't really guess your initial layout and that i don't have access to your images.

Words of advice:

Don't be afraid to use DIVs. They are containers, so you have more control over your layout.

Use background colors in your divs: This way you will see your blocks and know why some elements are not aligned or stacked correctly.

What i did:

- Take the Header and the Footer out of the wrapper
- Rearrange html structure by adding more divs
- I added color to each divs to have a better understanding of the layout
- In CSS, added to the body and html their own background color. This helps the footer to alway have a height of 100% if someone uses the browser zoom tool.
- Gave a Percentage width to each of the text divs at the bottom which totals 100% (Message and Contact)
- Gave min-height and height percentage to the wrapper

You will see that no element moves when the page is resized. If you have any questions, don't hesitate.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
    <title>Title Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        *{font: 12px arial;}
        html,body{margin:0;padding: 0;}
        body{background: #FFF;}
        html{background: #eb322c;}
        h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{padding: 0;margin: 0;}
        .header{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100px;
            background: #f2f2f2;
        }
        .center-div{
            width: 900px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .logo-container{
            background: #92F5AD;
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
            float: left;
        }
        .nav{
            float: right;
            background: #F5E255;
            height: 100px;
        }
        .nav ul {
            border-left: 1px;
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .nav li {
            float:left;
            display: block;
            padding: 8px 15px; 
            border-right: 2px solid #eb332c;
            position:relative;
            top:30px;
        }
        .nav li a:hover {
            color: #c00;background-color: #fff; 
        }
        .nav li.last{
            border-right:none;
        }
        .nav li a{
            text-decoration: none;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size:16px;
            color:#000;
        }   
        .wrapper{
            min-height: 100%;
            height: auto !important;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .mainContent{
            width: 900px;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            background: #D8D8D8;
        }
        .headings{
            width: 100%;
            display: block;
        }
        .top-container{
            width: 100%;
            height: 220px;
            display: block;
            padding-top: 50px;
            position: relative;
            padding-bottom: 100px;
        }
        .headtitle{
            background-color:#FFFFFF;
            text-align:left;
            font-size:30px;
            position:absolute;
            margin-top: 50px;
            z-index:100;
        }
        .img-container{
            float: left;
            width: 33.3%;
            height: 220px;
        }
        .img1{background: #f5f5f5;}
        .img2{background: #9DEBFF;}
        .img3{background: #9DFFC8;}
        .bottom-headings{
            clear: both;
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            padding-bottom: 50px;
        }
        .subTitle{
            display: inline-block;
            width: 33.1%;
        }
        .s1{background: #f5f5f5;}
        .s2{background: #9DEBFF;}
        .s3{background: #9DFFC8;}
        .info-container{
            width: 100%;
            height: 292px;
            background: #A59DFF;
            display: block;
        }
        .message-container{
            width: 60%;
            float: left;
            background: #71A59F;
        }
        .contact-container{
            width: 40%;
            display: inline-block;
            background: #71A582;
        }
        .infoTitle{
            border-bottom: 1px solid #eb332c;
        }
        .para, .lorem{
            padding-right: 50px;
        }
        .footer{
            background:#eb322c;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            clear:both;
            position: relative;
        }
        .footer p{
            color:#FFF;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header" class="header">
        <div class="center-div">
            <div class="logo-container">
                Logo
            </div>
            <div class="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li class="Home"><a href="#">Home  </a></li>
                    <li class="About"><a href="#">About Us </a></li>
                    <li class="Team"><a href="#">Our team  </a></li>
                    <li class="Services"><a href="#">Our Services  </a></li>
                    <li class="last"><a href="#"> Contact Us </a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="mainContent">
            <!-- HEADINGS CONTAINER -->
            <div class="headings">
                <div class="top-container">
                    <h1 class="headtitle">Local <span style="color:#eb332c;font-weight:bold">Billingham</span>  Solicitors Firm</h1>
                    <div class="img-container img1">

                    </div>
                    <div class="img-container img2">

                    </div>
                    <div class="img-container img3">

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="bottom-headings">
                    <h2 class="subTitle s1">Family Law</h2>
                    <h3 class="subTitle s2">Buying & Selling Property</h3>
                    <h4 class="subTitle s3">Wills, Trusts & Probate</h4>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Bottom Information Container -->
            <div class="info-container">
                <div class="message-container">
                    <h5 class="infoTitle">Welcome to Cochranes Law Firm</h5>
                    <p class="para">We are a family High Street Practice, in Billingham Town Centre, providing an
                        important service to the local community. we are wills and probate. buying and Selling, as well as Family law Solicitors in the Billingham and Stockton-on-tees area. If you would like any further information please feel free to contact us by phone, email or our contact form.
                        </p>
                        <p class="lorem"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed accumsan, urna sit amet euismod gravida, elit ante placerat orci, et porttitor nunc velit malesuada tortor. Nam ac nisl non nunc commodo vestibulum a eu velit. Sed vitae arcu sit amet nulla ornare fringilla sodales vel justo. Cras hendrerit libero a mauris gravida lobortis. Donec iaculis tincidunt est, non rutrum lorem dictum vitae. Curabitur non justo sed est accumsan posuere id eget justo. Nunc in justo congue, laoreet sem sed, scelerisque nulla. Fusce in urna suscipit, imperdiet purus et, ornare nunc. Ut vestibulum consectetur metus, vitae ultrices lacus placerat aliquet.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="contact-container">
                    <h5 class="infoTitle" class="address"> Contact Address</h6>
                    <p class="pclass">Cochranes Law Firm <br> 67 Queensway<br>
                        Billingham<br>TS23 2KH</p>
                        <h6 class="commonnum">Contact Numbers</h6>
                        <p class="nums">Telephone: 01642 266800<br>Fax:01642 366809<br>
                        DX 63160 BILLINGHAM</p>
                        <p class="Email">info@cochraneslawfirm.co.uk</p>
                        <h6 class="contactmail">Contact E-Mail Address</h6>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="footer">
        <div class="center-div">

            <p class="foot">&copy;2014 Cochranes Law Firm | Privacy Policy | Terms and Conditions
            Web Design by MCWare IT Solutions.</p>
            <img src="images/mcware.png">
            <img src="images/accreditations.png" class="accreditations">

           <p> <small>Cochranes Law Firm is a Limited Liability registered in England and Wales number OC343046 and our VAT number is 508 983002. The registered office is at 67 Queensway, Billingham. TS23 2LU. Authorised and regulated by the Solicitors Regulation authority number 547210 under rule 7.07(1) of the Solicitors Code Of Conduct. We have worldwide professional indemnity insurance through amtrust Europe Limited, No2 Minster Court, Minicing Lane, LONDON, EC3R 7BB. Our policy number is P13A298125P and P13B295219P.  </small></p>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Here is the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n5P46/)